# Jmeter - use csv for setting http header

Tags: testing, http-headers, jmeter

I want to set header for each request.

header is - 
"token:value"

For every request this header value will be different and I have a csv file having all tokens listed there. Now, like we use csv for POST data values, I want to use this csv file to set header for each request.

CSV file -
"token1,token2,token3"

How to do this in jmeter ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To achieve your goal, you should do following for each request:

1. Add [HTTP Header Manager](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Header_Manager):

[image]

2 . Add [CSV Data Set Config](http://community.blazemeter.com/knowledgebase/articles/65138-using-csv-data-set-config)  configured like this:

[image: CSV Data Set Config]

Answer (score 1):

the idea is pretty good, if the referer field is widely used.

I'm not sure that you can use CSV data sets, because it reads **ONE** line for **each user/ thread**.

In a situation similar to yours, I had to use a __CSVread function, that allows  to manually control if and when to read the next line.

Refer to: "CSVRead">http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#_CSVRead"

Answer (score 0):

If request the same but header changes, then you obviously need [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) element. Example of usage you can find in %JMETER_HOME%/bin/examples. If requests are different then I'm not sure it makes sens to use CSV file.